# Disable form on first submit and persist disabled state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a few forms that when submitted for the first time I need the fields and submit button to go into a disabled state and persist even on refresh.

Here is my form

```
{{> header}}

<div class="container">
  <form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post" class="competitionformlockdown">
    <h2>School Competition Form</h2>
    <p>
      <b>All fields with <span style="color: red">*</span> are required</b>
    </p>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        General Information
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="schoolName">
              School Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="schoolName" placeholder="Enter school name" value="{{competitions.schoolName}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6 date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <label for="competitionDate">
              Competition Date <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionDate" name="competitionDate" placeholder="Enter the date of competition" value="{{competitions.competitionDate}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTime">
              Time <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTime" name="competitionTime" placeholder="Enter the time of the competition (e.g. 8:00 AM)" value="{{competitions.competitionTime}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionVenue">
              Venue <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionVenue" name="competitionVenue" placeholder="Enter where the competition was held" value="{{competitions.competitionVenue}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalOfStudents">
              Total number of students in the program <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalOfStudents" name="competitionTotalOfStudents" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalOfStudents}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalParticipated">
              Total number of students that participated <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalParticipated" name="competitionTotalParticipated" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalParticipated}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalPersonnel">
              Total number of school personnel involved in the program <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalPersonnel" name="competitionTotalPersonnel" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalPersonnel}}" required>
          </div>
        </div><!-- row ends -->
      </div><!-- End of panel body -->
    </div><!-- School Information panel ends -->

    <!-- Judge 1 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 1
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Name" name="competitionJudge1Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Telephone" name="competitionJudge1Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Email" name="competitionJudge1Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- Judge 2 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 2
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Name" name="competitionJudge2Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Telephone" name="competitionJudge2Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Email" name="competitionJudge2Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- Judge 3 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 3
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Name" name="competitionJudge3Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Telephone" name="competitionJudge3Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Email" name="competitionJudge3Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- The following fields are hidden to users and should ONLY be visible and editable by a site admin-level user. -->
    {{#if user.admin}}
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Administrators Only
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Sent Required Photos? (currently {{competitions.competitionRequiredPhotos}})</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredPhotos" id="yesPhotosRadio" value="yes">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="yesPhotosRadio">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredPhotos" id="noPhotosRadio" value="no">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="noPhotosRadio">No</label>
        </div>

        <p>Sent Required Certifications? (currently {{competitions.competitionRequiredCertifications}})</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredCertifications" id="yesCertsRadio" value="yes">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="yesCertsRadio">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredCertifications" id="noCertsRadio" value="no">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="noCertsRadio">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <!-- End of fields hidden to user -->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

{{> footer}}
```

Here is what I have tried s far

```
  $('.formlockdown').on('submit',function(){
    var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).find('form'));
    if (mycookie && mycookie === "true") {
      $(this).closest('form').find("input").prop('disabled', true);
      $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(".competitionformlockdown").change(function() {
    $.cookie($(this).find("form"), $(this).prop('disabled'), {
      path: '/',
      expires: 365
    });
  });
```

So I want the form (after a first submit or if the form has been submitted for the cookie to trigger and activate the disabled attribute on all fields and the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using *cookies* for it. Web storage, *localStorage*, is meant to store data locally within the user's browser.

You can set:

```
localStorage.setItem('form1_submitted', '1')
```

.. and later get and check data from it, using:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('form1_submitted') == '1') {
   $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

In order to clear *localStorage* you would need to run:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

Comment: So if I'm right in thinking the code should look like this? https://gist.github.com/benbagley/c33933f0ff7601368ea5431d37dbce12

Comment: Ok so this sort of works, when I load the form now the forms go into a disabled state, I do want the user to be able to fill out the form once before this takes affect. They shouldn't be able to edit it after the first submit.

Comment: @B.J.B No. In case you set `formlockdown`, later you should get `formlockdown`, while you are getting `competitionformlockdown`. It will always return `false` in that case.

Comment: Ok I updated the question code, so to keep the forms separate, I have set a class `competitionformlockdown` to the form.

Comment: Is there a way to get the form to start with the value of zero then on submit change to 1?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want the user to be able to submit the form once, after that the forms should go into a disabled state and persist. The code that you have provided solves the disabled fields but now the user isn't able to fill out the form once as the fields are disabled so the forms have to be enabled first, the user fills out the form, on submit the disabled (localstorage) takes affect and the fields get disabled.

Comment: Ok here's what I have now https://gist.github.com/benbagley/c33933f0ff7601368ea5431d37dbce12 however the forms are still going into a disabled state right away, the localstorage are being set to 1 straight away, submit or no submit. This is a gif https://gyazo.com/c57fbfb0a7cb889bd02f09f89847dfbe see how in incognito mode competition results is disabled without it being submitted?